# Define a character as a word boundary

Tags: emacs, syntax

I've defined the `\` character to behave as a word constituent in latex-mode, and I'm pretty happy with the results. The only thing bothering me is that a sequence like `\alpha\beta` gets treated as a single word (which is the expected behavior, of course).

Is there a way to make emacs interpret a specific character as a word "starter"? This way it would always be considered part of the word following it, but never part of the word preceding it.

For clarity, here's an example:

```
\alpha\beta
^          ^
1          2
```

If the point is at `1` and I press `M-d`, the string "\alpha" should be killed.
If the point is at `2` and I press `M-<backspace>`, the string "\beta" should be killed.

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another thought:
Your requirement is very like what `subword-mode` provides for camelCase.

You can't customize subword-mode's behaviour -- the regexps are hard-coded -- but you could certainly copy that library and modify it for your purposes.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-library` <kbd>RET</kbd> `subword` <kbd>RET</kbd>

That would presumably be a pretty robust solution.

**Edit:** updated from the comments, as suggested:

> For the record, changing every instance of `[[:upper:]]` to `[\\\\[:upper:]]` in the functions `subword-forward-internal` and `subword-backward-internal` inside subword.el works great =) (as long as "\" is defined as "w" syntax).

Personally I would be more inclined to make a copy of the library than edit it directly, unless for the purpose of making the existing library a little more general-purpose, for which the simplest solution would seem to be to move those regexps into variables -- after which it would be trivial to have buffer-local modified versions for this kind of purpose.

**Edit 2:** As of Emacs 24.3 (currently a [release candidate](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.devel/157522)), subword-mode facilitates this with the new `subword-forward-regexp` and `subword-backward-regexp` variables (for simple modifications), and the `subword-forward-function` and `subword-backward-function` variables (for more complex modifications).

By making those regexp variables buffer-local in latex-mode with the desired values, you can just use subword-mode directly.

Comment: Yeah, I've been wondering if subword mode might be of any help. I'll check out the regexps.

Comment: Actually, if manage to get `\\` to be treated as uppercase, _subword-mode_ would do the rest for me. I think that's configured in *Syntax Properties*, but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Nice idea, but it rather looks to me as if you can't have an upper-case character without specifying its lower-case variant? (I'm looking at `Case Tables` and `Case Conversion` under `(elisp) Strings and Characters`, as well as the `[:upper:]` and `[:lower:]` definitions in `(elisp) Char Classes`.)

Comment: For the record, changing every instance of `[[:upper:]]` to `[\\\\[:upper:]]` in the functions `subword-forward-internal` and `subword-backward-internal` inside *subword.el* works great =) (as long as "\" is defined as "w" syntax). I'd still rather find a way of using _syntax properties_ (so I won't have to repeat it every time I update _subword.el_), but for now I'll accept your answer if you update it.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to implement this using syntax text properties:

<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(elisp) Syntax Properties")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

**Edit:** Actually, I'm not sure if you can do precisely this?

The following (which is just experimentation) is close, but `M-<backspace>` at 2 will only delete "beta" and not the preceding "\".

I suppose you could remap `backward-kill-word` to a function which checked for that preceding "\" and killed that as well. Fairly hacky, but it would probably do the trick if there's not a cleaner solution.

I haven't played with this functionality before; perhaps someone else can clarify.

```el
(modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "w")
(setq parse-sexp-lookup-properties t)
(setq syntax-propertize-function 'my-propertize-syntax)
(defun my-propertize-syntax (start end)
  "Set custom syntax properties."
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward "\\w\\\\" end t)
      (put-text-property
       (1- (point)) (point) 'syntax-table (cons "." ?\\)))))
```